# Visual Studio 2013 - images in the designer but not at runtime

Tags: wpf, image, visual-studio, xaml, resources

Weird issue in Visual Studio within my WPF project.

I have deleted some images (gif and png files) from my folder. I have recovered them and re-added as resource of my application.

Now I can see the images in the design window of my xaml but I can't see these images when I execute the application. Why?

The images are all in the same folder and those I haven't deleted are still working perfectly.

This is the code of a not-working image (as I said, I see it only in the designer window):

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Autisti}" x:Name="msmi_Autisti" Tag="AUTISTI" Command="{Binding ApriAutisti}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding canReadAutisti}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/autisti.gif" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

And this is the code of a working one (it's the same code!)

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Veicoli}" x:Name="msmi_Veicoli" Tag="VEICOLI" Command="{Binding ApriVeicoli}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding canReadVeicoli}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/veicoli.gif" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Here the properties of two files, one working and one not

[image]

**UPDATE**: look the comments for the solution

Comment: Did you set the build action of the image file to "Resource"?

Comment: And do compare everything (esp Build Action) between a working and a nonworking image.

Comment: @AneesDeen Yes, after I have written the question. I thought I have found the solution, but nothing changed..

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think yes, what else can I compare?

Comment: Do clean and build again

Comment: @Malcolm Done and.. solved it!!! I have tried a rebuild before and I was thinking it is the same of "clean&build"... thanks, man!!!!